# django contenttype and string comparison

Tags: django, django-templates, content-type

I have a model with ContentType field in it.

In any model method I can compare it to the string:

```
self.content_type == "construction" # True if ContentObject points to Construction model.
```

However, such thing doesn't seem to work in templates.

First thing I tried

```
{% if object.content_type == "construction" %}
```

And second:

```
def __unicode__(self): 
    return str(self.content_type)
`{% if object == "construction" %}`
```

and it's False, but {{ object }} prints `construction`.

Comment: Try: `{% if object.content_type.model == "construction" %}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The unicode method for `ContentType` simply displays the name, which is why `{{ object }}` displays `construction` in the template.

```
class ContentType(models.Model):
    ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

However, `object.content_type` is a `ContentType` instance, not a string, so comparing it to "construction" will always return `False`. Try comparing the content type's `model` instead.

```
{% if object.content_type.model == "construction" %}
```